"return" placement in the static bool function causing the function to execute only the first time it is called
I have a static bool function that checks if the mouse button is released.
There was one problem that i managed to fix but i still have no idea why it didn't work then and why it works now.
Heres the problem:
If i place my return false inside "if (isMInputReleased == true)" statement like this:
//"isMInputPressed" and "isMInputReleased" are both a bool variables initialized in the header file. What you see below is the cpp file

bool IsReleased::IsButtonReleased(sf::Mouse::Button button)
{

    if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(button))
    {
        isMInputPressed = true;
    }
    //if isMInputPressed is true and you dont press the input button anymore then toggle isMInputPressed to false and isMInputReleased to true
    else if (isMInputPressed == true)
    {
        isMInputPressed = false;
        isMInputReleased = true;
        return true;
    }

    if (isMInputReleased == true)
    {
        isMInputReleased = false;
        //return false;  <-- if i uncomment this, the second time this function is called, it stops working (it only works for the first call) Why?
    }
    else return false; // <-- this works though (also worked with no default return value)
}

The function works only the first time it is called. Example:
int main()
{
grid.Update(windowME); //uses IsReleased::IsButtonReleased, works  <-- whatever is called first //will always work
toolbar.Update(mousepos); //uses IsReleased::IsButtonReleased, doesn't work <-- whatever is called
//after the first call doesn't work
}

But if i place the "return false" outside of that statement, as a default return value, then it works, all functions calls trigger.
Why didn't the commented code work?
PS. Here's an example of the use of "IsButtonReleased" function:
//if left mouse button is released then execute the code inside the statement
if (IsReleased::IsButtonReleased(sf::Mouse::Button::Left) == true)
{
 //execute code inside here
}

By messing around for a while, changing random things to see if it changes anything, i found that if i dont use return false anywhere, neither inside the "if (isMInputReleased == true)" statement and neither as a default return value, the code also works as intended and every fucnction call executes properly.

Side note: changing random things to see if it changes anything is called Shotgun debugging. It is notoriously inefficient and often adds rather than removes bugs due to detritus left by the experiments. Don't do it.

Instead, run the program in a debugger. Place a breakpoint in the function and step through it line by line so you can see exactly what the program does and the variables that lead to that decision. When you can see WHY the program failed, figuring out what to do instead is usually a cakewalk.

Note that in the code snippet shown if if (isMInputReleased == true) evaluates to true then your function doesn't return a value -- so undefined behaviour.

@user4581301 Originally i actually tried changing thing that i thought would be reasonable and i used cout to debug since it was a cleaner and easiest way to debug than using breakpoints in this specific situation (at least for me)
It was later that i just intuitively started changing the structure of the function return order and manage to fix the problem unintentionally. I can't really understand why it worked, thats why im here

@G.M. yeah i was aware of that but it was the closest to correct at the time.
thankfully i found the proper solution a little later.
The problem is that i still don't know why does it work

I asked chatGPT before i decided to post this question on stack overflow, and it said that i prematurely returned that false value, thats why it didn't work.
I wasn't satisfied with that explaination, because it wasn't clear enough, and i'd rather have a real human explain it.
This specific code was very hard to debug for various reasons, so i don't have much resources to reflect on. Just that chatGPT's answer.

The problem is that i still don't know why does it work  Undefined behavior has undefined behavior.  It can appear to work, which is allowed and acceptable undefined behavior.

Remember that Chat GPT is a language model, and that the language it models is NOT C++. It can't understand C++. The best it can do is look in its database of text for inputs that appear to match and parrot the results it finds. It's really good for really common software problems because of the volume of pre-existing material about the problem that it can work from, but as it finds fewer and fewer examples, the results get worse quickly and dramatically.

@user4581301 I didn't know that chatGPT doesn't understand C++ syntax, but either way i never trusted ai and investigated on my own every time. If i ended up deciding to ask chatGPtT about some code, i always carefully scanned its anwser and analyzed if it even makes sense. Now i know that lack of trust was on point, thank you for clarifying how it works.

You never explained what "doesn't work" even means. What outcome do you expect, and what do you observe instead?

As written, your function only ever returns true under one very specific circumstance: if it's called while the button was pressed, it would then return true exactly once after the button is released. Is this what you meant to do? isMInputReleased variable is pointless - you assign a value to it, and you check that value later, but you do the exact same thing (namely, return false;) whether that variable is true or false. With all due respect, the code makes no sense to me; it's entirely unclear what you were trying to achieve.

@IgorTandetnik What i was trying to achieve is to make a function that checks if the button is released.
I needed to make a function like this, because when i press the button in my app, by using SFML's isButtonPressed function, it spammed that button if i were holding left mouse button, and i wanted the button to only trigger once.
the isMInputReleased is required to prevent the spam.
For some reason this simple task ended up being very hard for me, thats why it's a mess.
Also by "It doesn't work", i meant that this code makes the function trigger only the first time its called.

This is the only way i found for the code for it to work as intended, its just odd that when i returned false inside the if (isMInputReleased == true) statement, i get the bug i described in the post :                        ,
bool IsReleased::IsButtonReleased(sf::Mouse::Button button)
{
if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(button))
{
isMInputPressed = true;
}
else if (isMInputPressed == true)
{
isMInputPressed = false;
isMInputReleased = true;
return true;
}
if (isMInputReleased == true)
{
isMInputReleased = false;
}
else return false;
}

I don't have to return false at all, but i'd rather add a default return value for readability and to be less likely to ecounter bugs (also sorry for the code in the comment being hard to read, comments don't register moving to the new line. Just copy and paste it to text editor and separate the code, so its readable.)

Isn't "button is released" just the opposite of "button is pressed"? As in, return !sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(button);? If not, what exactly is your definition of "button is released"? In English, not in code.

if i would do: !sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(button); , the code would always trigger if i'm not pressing the specified button. I definitely don't want that to happen. I want to check if the button is pressed first, if yes, then as soon as that button is released, return true once.
